# Announcing a Pro Tempore Moderator election - Nominations begin August 10th

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Arts & Crafts Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **August 10th** to bring in two more moderators.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on August 10th, users can [nominate themselves](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On August 17, if there are three or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidate/s. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, we'll announce the results on meta on August 25th.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Just double-checking:
As this is a Pro Tempore election, there won‘t be a candidate questionnaire? Or am I missing something?

Comment: That's correct. If there were, it would have started last week :D So this is just a simple, "step up and then vote". :)