# What are the voting requirements for a Pro Tempore Moderator election?

Tags: discussion, election

There is an [upcoming moderator election](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/401/9298). This election has been labeled a *special, pro tempore, moderator election*. [This meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135361/520220) states that the requirement to vote in a moderator election is 150 reputation (assuming more candidates have been nominated than available positions).

Will this pro tempore election require 150 reputation to vote (if there are enough candidates)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, all moderator elections (pro-tempore or regular ones) require 150 reputation. [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314459/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange lists the differences, and the 150 reputation requirement is not mentioned. I've voted in several pro-tempore elections across the network and didn't notice a difference either.